# mosh: sources .bashrc twice with different PIDs

Tags: bash, tmux, mosh

I use `tmux` in my build server. Recently I wrote a small `.bashrc` script that will automate attaching to `tmux` session if one exits. The script looks like follows

```
# Automate tmux Startup                                                                                                                                                                                     
if [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then                                                                                                                                                                                     
    # we're not in a tmux session                                                                                                                                                                           
   if [ `ps -o comm= -p $PPID` == "sshd" ]; then                                                                                                                                                            
        # even VNC can have $SSH_TTY and $SSH_CONNECTION set so we cant find out                                                                                                                            
        # if we want to attach to tmux during ssh so we need to see if parent                                                                                                                               
        # process is sshd see                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        # http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145780/linux-ssh-connection-is-set-even-  without-sshing-to-the-server                                                                                      
        # Only attach to tmux if its me                                                                                                                                                                     
        WHOAMI=$(whoami)                                                                                                                                                                                    
        if tmux has-session -t $WHOAMI 2>/dev/null; then                                                                                                                                                    
            tmux -2 attach-session -t $WHOAMI                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        else                                                                                                                                                                                                
           echo "Start tmux with username as session name 'tmux new -s $WHOAMI' "                                                                                                                          
        fi                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     fi #parent process check                                                                                                                                                                                
else                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   echo "Inside tmux"                                                                                                                                                                                       
fi
```

The problem is whenever I `ssh` using `mosh` it just hangs inside the tmux window. I found that if I remove this script and then use mosh to just ssh and attach to tmux manually then I don't hit on this issue. This issue only happens if I place the above script in `.bashrc`.

My suspicion was that mosh is waiting for `.bashrc` to complete and waits for it indefinitely and in the mean time it also does not pass the mouse and keystroke controls over to `tmux`. I confirmed this by killing the `tmux` session from another terminal and found that `mosh` recovered and tried to execute my previously buffered keystrokes.

The strange thing is that how `mosh` managed to cross the `ps -o comm= -p $PPID == "sshd"` check. This is because for `mosh` the Process name of shell is `bash` and Parent process name of the shell is `mosh-server` and not `sshd`. Further investigation revealed that `mosh` executes `.bashrc` twice once as `sshd` and once as `mosh-server`. This is reproducible by putting `ps -o comm= -p $PID -p $$ >> moshbash` in `.bashrc`.My `tmux attach` was happening in `sshd` and hanging `mosh` forever.

A simple workaround I found was to do

> mosh user@server -- tmux attach -t `whoami`

I can do a similar thing to my ssh as well to fire command from the client side and eliminate the .bashrc script altogether but I do not wish to spill over my server side automation to the client side.

Actually `mosh` does not seem to be wrong. It is sourcing a `.bashrc` file only once per PID .I think it is a bad design to have `.bashrc` kick of a blocking session to `tmux` since `tmux` also needs terminal we cant start off as a background process either so `&` also wont work. 
Is there any other way around this problem ? I think if we can distingusih between a mosh client setting up a sshd and a ssh client setting up sshd that information can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.bashrc` always executes everytime an interactive non-login bash instantiates so use `.bash_profile` instead so it would only run once during login to ssh. If the script or processes of the script summons bash, it would cause repeated summoning.

See [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) for more info and other startup files.